# How to pass information to the View Layer during a long process in the Model/Adaptor Layer

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find the correct approach to communicating back and forth between the View and Model/Adapter Layers in an MVC model. The following is some psuedo-code of my issue, and what I want it to do. See the comments in the MyAdapter.ImportStuff method for explanations.

```
public class MyView : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{
    private MyContoller Ctrl = new MyContoller();
    public MyView()
    {
    }

    private void OnButtonClick()
    {
        Ctrl.DoSqlStuffNow();
        TellUserImportFinished();
    }

    public void TellUserThingsHaveBeenDeleted()
    {
        this.label1.Text = "Stuff deleted...";
    }
    public void TellUserHowManyRowsHaveBeenInserted(int rowCount)
    {
        this.label2.Text = $"Number of rows inserted: {rowCount}...";
    }
    public void TellUserComplexQueriesAreDone()
    {
        this.label3.Text = "Complex queries are done...";
    }
    public void TellUserImportFinished()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Success!");
    }
}
internal class MyContoller
{
    MyAdapter Adpt = new MyAdapter();
    internal void DoSqlStuffNow()
    {
        object someParameter = new object();
        Adpt.ImportStuff(someParameter);
    }
}
internal class MyAdapter
{
    internal void ImportStuff(object someParameter)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("connection");

        // All of this has to happen in one connection/transaction.
        // It should not be broken into multiple methods

        DeleteFromTable1();
        DeleteFromTable2();
        // Now I want to tell the user delete is complete!

        MakeTempTable();
        InsertIntoTempTable(someParameter);
        int rowCount = ImportIntoTable1();
        // Now I want to tell the user how many rows were just inserted!

        DoComplexQuery();
        DoAnotherComplexQuery();
        // Now I want to tell the user complex queries are done!

        ImportIntoTable2();
        DropTempTable();
        // Presumably, I can say "success" when this function returns, which is fine
    }
}
```

My particular case is even worse since the Controller/Adapter are actually static classes, so event's aren't fun to deal with, but I'm not even sure how best to handle it in this simple case.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would not over complicate stuffs. Looking at the design you have I would go with Events in the Adapter class and bindings in the `MyView`.

You create 4 events based on what you want to notify. As everything is happening in a single method you could also have 1 event and 4 different status. Though, I don't like this approach since it would require a bunch of IFs later in the event handlers.

You can write your own delegates of course but for simplicity I did use the EventHandler class.

```
    public event EventHandler DeleteCompleted;

    //int: the number of rows inserted
    public event EventHandler<int> RowsInserted;

    public event EventHandler ComplexQuerycCompleted;

    //bool: if the operation completed successfully.
    public event EventHandler<bool> OperationCompleted;
```

Another advantage of multiple events is that let's say a part of your app only wants to know when the operation is completed but nothing else you would only subscribe to that specific event.

Modify your class to call the events where ever you need.

```
internal class MyAdapter
{

    public event EventHandler DeleteCompleted;

    public event EventHandler<int> RowsInserted;

    public event EventHandler ComplexQuerycCompleted;

    public event EventHandler<bool> OperationCompleted;


    internal void ImportStuff(object someParameter)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("connection");

        // All of this has to happen in one connection/transaction.
        // It should not be broken into multiple methods

        DeleteFromTable1();
        DeleteFromTable2();
        // Now I want to tell the user delete is complete!

        this.DeleteCompleted?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());

        MakeTempTable();
        InsertIntoTempTable(someParameter);
        int rowCount = ImportIntoTable1();

        // Now I want to tell the user how many rows were just inserted!
        this.RowsInserted?.Invoke(this, rowCount);

        DoComplexQuery();
        DoAnotherComplexQuery();

        // Now I want to tell the user complex queries are done!
        this.ComplexQuerycCompleted.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());

        ImportIntoTable2();
        DropTempTable();

        // Presumably, I can say "success" when this function returns, which is fine
        this.OperationCompleted?.Invoke(this, true);
    }
}
```

In your `MyController` class you can subscribe to the events you need. In this class you can implement the INotifyPropertyChanged (MVVM) so that you notify the `MyView` View about changes in from the adapter.

```
internal class MyContoller : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    MyAdapter Adpt = new MyAdapter();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int rowsInserted;
    public int RowsInserted 
    {
        get { return rowsInserted;}
        set 
        {
            if (rowsInserted == value)
                return;

            rowsInserted = value;
            RaisedPropertyChanged(nameof(RowsInserted));
        }
    }

    internal MyContoller()
    { 
        //Remember to remote the event subscriptions calling:
        // Adpt.RowsInserted -= OnRowsInserted
        Adpt.RowsInserted += OnRowsInserted;
    }

    internal void DoSqlStuffNow()
    {
        object someParameter = new object();
        Adpt.ImportStuff(someParameter);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raiseds the property changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Property name.</param>
    protected void RaisedPropertyChanged([CallerMemberNameAttribute] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the Rows has been inserted in the <see cref="MyAdapter"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Sender</param>
    /// <param name="numberOfRows">The Number of rows in inserted</param>
    void OnRowsInserted(object sender, int numberOfRows)
    {
        //Notify the UI about objects inserted
        RowsInserted = numberOfRows;
    }
}
```

Later in your view you bind the properties from the `MyController` to the UI Controls you are using to reflect the changes.

Read about Databinding [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx).

I am not clear when you said " the Controller/Adapter are actually static classes" but I think the above can really help you.

Another option of course is using [ReactiveUI](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/801986/using-reactiveui-for-winforms-mvvm-design), but this one would require you to learn about Rx.Net and programming in a reactive way.